# Converting a shapefile from easting/northing to lat/long

Tags: coordinate-system, r, latitude-longitude, rgdal

I am working with an open data shapefile that uses easting/northing coordinates.  My geocoded data set uses lat/long, so I am trying to reproject/transform the shapefile to use lat/long.

````
```{r}
nwk_shp <- st_read('http://data.ci.newark.nj.us/dataset/61038922-a789-4abe-9928-79f9fe96c307/resource/90ead04f-dffd-4b3a-93c7-39cd4b190d4f/download/superneighborhoodswgs84.geojson') %>% 
  as('Spatial')
```

Reading layer `OGRGeoJSON' from data source `http://data.ci.newark.nj.us/dataset/61038922-a789-4abe-9928-79f9fe96c307/resource/90ead04f-dffd-4b3a-93c7-39cd4b190d4f/download/superneighborhoodswgs84.geojson' using driver `GeoJSON'
Simple feature collection with 21 features and 8 fields
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 561009.6 ymin: 671183.6 xmax: 598979.6 ymax: 712226.2
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
````

The shapefile uses northing/easting coordinates:

````
```{r}
nwk_shp@data[1:3, ] %>% select(-AREA, -PERIMETER, -CATEGORY)
```
1   0     18         LOWER CLINTON HILL   686419.4  575672.5
2   1      8 MT PLEASANT/LOWER BROADWAY   701184.5  583709.9
3   2     12            LOWER ROSEVILLE   701167.2  577849.7
````

Here is the projection string on my shapefile:

````
```{r}
proj4string(nwk_shp)
```
[1] "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
````

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018098/how-to-convert-utm-coordinates-to-lat-and-long-in-r) tutorial, and several others, I have tried several variations on `spTransform` - none of which seem to transform my data into expected lat/longitude coordinates.

For instance:

````
```{r}

nwk_shp_transformed <- spTransform(nwk_shp, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

nwk_shp_transformed@data[1:3, ] %>% select(-AREA, -PERIMETER, -CATEGORY)
```
 FID MSLINK                       NAME NORTHING_Y EASTING_X
1   0     18         LOWER CLINTON HILL   686419.4  575672.5
2   1      8 MT PLEASANT/LOWER BROADWAY   701184.5  583709.9
3   2     12            LOWER ROSEVILLE   701167.2  577849.7
````

Depending on what common lat/long CRS I use, I get a 'non-finite transformation detected':

````
```{r}

nwk_shp_again <- spTransform(nwk_shp, CRS("+init=epsg:4238"))

nwk_shp_again@data[1:3, ] %>% select(-AREA, -PERIMETER, -CATEGORY)
```
35 projected point(s) not finitenon finite transformation detected:
[1] 574389.9 685357.4      Inf      Inf
Error in .spTransform_Polygon(input[[i]], to_args = to_args, from_args = from_args,  : 
  failure in Polygons 1 Polygon 1 points 1
````

All of this leads me to suspect that there's something about either

- the proj string of the original shapefile?
- something omitted from the CRS I am using in my `spTransform` command?
  at work here.

I've read the ['Overview of Coordinate Reference Systems in R'](https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/~frazier/RSpatialGuides/OverviewCoordinateReferenceSystems.pdf) but am still stuck.

Desired output would be a shapefile / SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with coordinates in lat / longitude - eg, Latitudes around 40 degrees, and Longitudes around -74 degrees.

Comment: This `nwk_shp@data[1:3, ]` can't possibly work after reading with `sf::st_read`. You have a mix of sf and sp code here, can you be sure and choose one or the other - there's a list of analogous functions between the packages here https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/wiki/Migrating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're correct with your first suspicion, the original proj4string is incorrectly defined as `"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"`. You can tell because the coordinates don't look like longitude/latitude decimal degrees.

If you knew the correct coordinate system of the original data, you could correct the proj4string like this

```
new_shp@proj4string <- CRS("+proj=the correct proj parameters")
```

and then call spTransform like you did

```
nwk_shp_transformed <- spTransform(nwk_shp, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
```

I tried this, guessing that the correct coordinate system of the original was [web mercator](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7483/proj4/), but that didn't seem to be correct either.

Looking at the original data source - http://data.ci.newark.nj.us/dataset/newark-neighborhoods/resource/90ead04f-dffd-4b3a-93c7-39cd4b190d4f - the problem is pretty clearly on their end.

But this *might* be a working version of the same? http://data.ci.newark.nj.us/dataset/newark-neighborhoods/resource/fcbbb04d-4684-439c-886f-929cb4e7c200

Comment: This worked wonderfully!  For the record, I used `proj4string(nwk_shp) <- CRS("+init:epsg:3424")` per @mkennedy below

Answer (score 2):

The coordinate values in the nwk_shp appear to be using a New Jersey State Plane zone, units = US survey feet, based on NAD 1983 or a later re-adjustment (like NAD 1983 (2011), which one is impossible to determine by inspection). The EPSG well-known ID for the NAD 1983 version is 3424.